# node-sass compile scss files into a sub folder

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I want to output compiled css files in sub-directories relative to where the source scss files were found. I'm using the cli of node-sass,

(technically I'm using node-sass-chokidar, but that shouldn't make a difference, its just a wrapper for node-sass).

e.g.

```
code/
  dir1/
    style.scss
    css/
      style.css
  dir2/
    anotherstyle.scss
    css/
      anotherstyle.css
```

I need something like this to work: `node-sass code/* -o code/*/css/`, but that doesn't work :p.

I will also need to be able to watch files for changes, so a proposed answer should keep this in mind. e.g. looping over each file individually would be an incompatible solution because I would not be able to use node-sass's --watch flag.

Answer (score -1):

In your command you should leave the `-o` tag and add `-w` for watching features.

So you should try something like that `node-sass -w code/source code/destination`

If you can’t use `-w` flag you could use a task runner like Gulp that do what you’re trying to do.

Comment: My biggest problem isn't figuring out how to get node-sass to watch files, I've been able to do that successfully in the past. My biggest problem is figuring out how to get the destination files into a subdirector. So the final command I'm looking for I presume would be something like `node-sass code/* -o ???`, I'm just not sure what to put in ??? to get it to work. After I get that working, I should easily be able to tack on the --watch part when I need to.

Comment: You should replace ??? with the desidered subdirectory starting from package.json dir.

Comment: So what would you use for the example folder structure I gave above? Because in that folder structure there would be more then one output sub-directory: code/dir1/css and code/dir2/css, depending on where the scss file was found. (We can say that the parent directory of code contains the package.json)